# Is there an alternative to builder pattern in Kotlin that I don't need to rewrite all attributes?

Tags: kotlin

Is there an alternative to builder pattern in Kotlin that I don't need to rewrite all attributes?

I read a lot of discussions about this, but none conclusive enough nor something that helps me.

I'm trying to do something like this, but it doesn't work because of the private set:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime
import java.time.OffsetDateTime.now
import java.util.UUID
import java.util.UUID.randomUUID

data class UserEntity(
    val id: UUID = randomUUID(),
) {
    var firstName: String = ""
        private set
    var lastName: String = ""
        private set
    var mainEmail: String = ""
        private set
    var isActive: Boolean = true
        private set
    var createdAt: OffsetDateTime = now()
        private set

    companion object {
        fun new(id: UUID = randomUUID(), block: UserEntity.() -> Unit): UserEntity {
            return UserEntity(id).apply(block).apply{this.validate()}
        }
    }

    fun update(block: UserEntity.() -> Unit) {
        this.apply(block).apply{this.validate()}
    }

    private fun validate(){
        // validations and throw errors here
    }
}

//============================================================
// to use like this

val userEntity = UserEntity.new {
    firstName = "User"
    lastName = "Last"
    mainEmail = "user.last@email.com"
}

userEntity.update {
    firstName = "Qwerty"
    lastName = "Another"
    mainEmail = "qwerty.another@email.com"
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't put those properties in the constructor as `val`s? This is kind of a bizarre data class because it is full of properties that don't participate in the `copy()`, `hascode()` and `equals()` functions.

Comment: I don't know Kotlin, but in Java with Lombok or ImmutableObjects libraries, you can use copy constructors and `withX` methods to construct new instances from existing ones

Comment: I don't think this is possible without a separate mutable type. Of course you can look for some compiler plugin that generates this automatically. But I agree with @Tenfour04 : your data class is definitely weird. You should either include all properties or make it not data class, because it doesn't work like a data class.

Comment: If you do put the properties in the constructor, then you can use named parameters when calling the constructor instead of the builder pattern.

Comment: This is very much not an idiomatic `data class`. It's an ordinary Java-style `class` that someone accidentally put the word `data` in front of.

Comment: The use of data is optional, I don't need to be a data class, my goal is to not create an entity and change the values of it directly.

I want to call validate() when a entity is created or updated, and block any way to update the values directly.

The class can be completely different, I just want to do like I told

Answer (score 1):

There is a `copy` method. In Kotlin data classes should be rather immutable, look at this example:

```kotlin
        data class User(
            val id: UUID =  UUID.randomUUID(),
            val name: String,
            val isActivated: Boolean = false
        ) {

            fun activate(): User {
                return this.copy(isActivated = true)
            }
        }
        
        val user = User(name = "John")
        val withNewName = user.copy(name = "Kate")
        val activatedKate = withNewName.activate()
```